# Format XElement object

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

How can I format the contents of an XElement object?

I know that the output string is automatically formatted when calling .ToString(), but I want to add the whitespace nodes before converting the objects to string.

The intention is to format XML nodes in the model that is generated by the Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor classes.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: What do you call *whitespace nodes*?

Comment: XText objects with whitespace as content.

Answer (score 2):

Add text as child element (stored as XText):

```
   string xml = "<a><b>b</b></a>";
   XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
   var b = xdoc.Element("b");
   b.AddBeforeSelf("  ");
   b.AddAfterSelf(new XText("   "));
   b.Add("  ");
   b.AddFirst("  ");
   Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

Example of universal formating (any xml):

```
   string xml = "<a><b a=\"a\"><c><d>d</d></c></b><b a=\"a\"><c><d>d</d></c></b><e b=\"b\" a=\"a\"><f>f</f></e></a>";
   XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(xml);
   Format(xdoc, 0);
   Console.WriteLine(xdoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));

    static void Format(XElement x, int level)
    {
        foreach (var x1 in x.Elements())
            Format(x1, level + 1);
        if (level > 0)
        {
            x.AddBeforeSelf(Environment.NewLine + new string(' ', 2 * level));
            if (x.Parent.LastNode == x)
            {
                string ending = Environment.NewLine;
                if (level > 1)
                    ending += new string(' ', 2 * (level - 1));
                x.AddAfterSelf(ending);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to add the whitespace in the XElement objects itself, instead of the string output.

Comment: xelement does not store whitespaces. it is not a string. it stores content of tag (inside <>...</>), content of attributes, but not a content before or after <>. please, do not give negative reputation. thanks )

Comment: just press F12 on xelement and look declaration. It has Name, Value properties, Attributes() method. There is no Whitespace property.

Comment: I know, but an XElement can have XText children objects, with whitespace as content.

Comment: you are right. xelement can has any xnode in children elements. updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But how can an XElement be formatted when it doesn't have fixed child content?

Comment: added formating function to example. writes newlines and spaces to each xelement. analog of xdoc.ToString(SaveOptions.None)